# Query about range & lists python

Tags: python

I have a list of values and I want to create a for loop such that in each iteration the range function gets a different start value from list, whereas the end value is same. I use `len` function but it is not what I need. How should I do it?

```
list_values = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

for x in range(len(list_values), 600):
    print(x)
```

I want the start value of loop to be changed as 0, 100, 200, 300 etc. in each iteration of loop e.g.

```
for x in range(0,600)
for x in range(100,600)
for x in range(200,600) etc.
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you want, but you seem to need a nested loop.

Comment: Iterate over the values: `for start in list_values:` and then construct the ranges: `for x in range(start, 600):`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an outer loop to iterate on `list_values` then the inner loop have the range

```
list_values = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
end_value = 600
for start_value in list_values:
    for x in range(start_value, end_value):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? The loop counts from 0 to 600, then it restarts and counts from 100 to 600, and so forth...

```
list_values = [0, 100,200,300,400,500]

for item in list_values:
    for x in range(item, 600):
        print(x)
```